# Is there an expression for people who are not there at all?

Tags: idiom-request

[image]

Ideally, an expression with eye, and that tells you that the person seems to have lost consciousness or is not fully there.

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&ns0=1&search=eyes+insource%3Aenglish+idioms

The best expression I was able to find was "she was like out cold", but couldn't find anything with eyes.

Comment: What is the relevance of the picture?  Why do you need an expression with the word "eye"? Your title and body ask different questions "Not there at all" is different from "seems to have lost consciousness"

Comment: Are you trying to translate an idiom?

Comment: Don't all those manga-cartoon people have weird eyes like that? Like they have green cataracts?

Comment: Dead-eyed.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead-eyed

Comment: _[Completely] out of it._

Comment: In addition to James K's concerns above, please give a few examples of a situations where someone might have eyes like you're describing. What made them "seem to have lost unconscious" or not be "fully there"? What are they still able to do? Is it more like "thousand yard stare", or are they completely unresponsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some expressions that come to mind are **out like a light**, **dead to the world**, **knocked out** and **out cold**.

If the person was not yet fully unconscious, you might say they were **seeing stars**. I think it's a reference to how that situation is often portrayed in a cartoon. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can say that someone's eyes have **glazed**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glazed) has

> **glazed**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **3** (of a person's eyes or expression) showing no interest or animation.
> *she had a glazed look in her eyes*

---

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/glazed+over) has

> **glaze over**
>
> **3** To begin to look lifeless or dull. Typically used to describe someone's eyes.
> *Your eyes have glazed over—did you work another 18-hour shift today?*
> *The lecture was so boring that everyone's eyes started glazing over about halfway through.*

<sub>*Footnote: there is no animation.*</sub>